# usage of adverb never

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Is this sentence correct? "We had a fight and never spoke again". I think the verb "spoke" should be either in simple present or present perfect, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, either would be fine. But note that it's _we never spoke_ or _we've never spoken_. With the perfect, but not the past, _since_ could replace _again_.

Comment: If you are suggesting that, "We had a fight and never speak again." might be correct the answer is. "No."  You might use the *historical present* and say, "[In 1980] we *have* a fight and never *speak* again."    "We had a fight and never spoke again." might be used when the person has died and there is no more chance of speaking.  "We had a fight and have never spoken again." might be used when the person is still living and a chance remains for speaking in the future.

Comment: Or you could say *"We had a fight and never speak anymore"*.

Comment: Good point @PeterShor

Answer (score 1):

An adverb doesn't change the tense of the verb.

> - I walk in the park.
> - I *rarely* walk in the park.
> - I swam to the raft.
> - I *quickly* swam to the raft.

In your sentence, "We had a fight and *never spoke* again", the reason *speak* is in the past is because it agrees with a verb in the past which places the action of *speak* in the past. *Never* has nothing to do with it. One can do the same by making the negative another way:

> - We had a fight and *did not* speak again.

Here, *did speak* places it in the past.

Likewise, if the second action takes place in the present, *never* has no effect over that either.

> - We had a fight and *never* speak anymore.

Comment: Just because a verb is preceded by a verb in the past, it doesn't have to be in the past: *"We had a fight and never speak anymore".*

Comment: @PeterShor True enough. I will edit.